# laravel 5.1 notfoundhttpexception for all the requests except '/'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is my route

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {    return 'reached'; });
Route::post('first', function () {    return 'first'; });
```

I can able to see the result as `reached` if i run

```
localhost/project
```

But i can't see the output `first` if i run `localhost/project/first`

**What could be the issue ?**

I just installed `illuminate/html` after fresh installation.

**Update :**

I even tried

```
Route::get('first', function () {    return 'first'; });
```

Comment: Quite hard to understand your question. When debugging routes it can be helpful to run the artisan command "artisan route:list". This gives you a list of all the routes for your application and would allow you to check that everything is as you want it to be.

Comment: when i run the command, i am getting this as output .. http://postimg.org/image/71whv8wzx/

Comment: Try to use the `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: same issue, even after trying it\

Comment: Use composer in the folder where there has artisan.php

Comment: Yes, i am having the composer only in that location

Comment: Actually  i traced the probelm.. pls read this .. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88989/discussion-between-vishal-sh-and-anto

Comment: But still need to fix the issue, that continues..

Comment: use /first in your route

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin Even i tried it

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, the url `localhost/project` points to the `index.php` file in your public folder. That seems to be functioning fine, however to access any other page you must enable `mod_rewrite` in apache.

- Navigate to the `httpd.conf` file in your apache folder
- Search for `mod_rewrite`, then uncomment the line by removing the `#`
- Restart your apache server and try again.